# Ошибка проекта на риакте - React.createClass is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Только начал изучать данную технологию
Запустил в браузере, и ошибка. 
Не пойму что не так

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    
    <script type="text/babel">
        var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
            render: function () {
                return <h1>Hello my world</h1>;
            }
        });

    ReactDOM.render(
        <HelloWorld />,
        document.getElementById("content")
    );
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как уже ответили, createClass убран и вообще устарел, зачем он вам.. Кстати, вот хороший ресурс дял быстрого прототипирования https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 1):

React убрал `createClass` начиная с версии 16. Вы можете использовать `create-react-class`, как сказано в документации.

```
// Before (15.4 and below)
var React = require('react');

var Component = React.createClass({
  mixins: [MixinA],
  render() {
    return <Child />;
  }
});

// After (15.5)
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var Component = createReactClass({
  mixins: [MixinA],
  render() {
    return <Child />;
  }
});
```

[Подробнее](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass)